# How to render the results of JSON in HTML without placeholder DIVS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

**User Story:** A user can search wikipedia. The results are limited to 5 articles, and the user can see the title + introduction of the article.

**Dev Story:** The query is given via HTML input field. The wikipedia API is requested via getJSON and the data given organized and given out to placeholder divs in a for loop.

**Question:** What can I do to remove the repetiveness in HTML? I'd like to remove the placeholder divs. 
To be more specific: Instead of having 5x divs for each result, I'd like to have one dynamic.

The code is working, see below. Working Example - Github pages [HERE](https://mkandut.github.io/Instant-Wikipedia-Search/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Custom CSS -->
 <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans');
 
    /*
    #300032
    #06000a
    #c43235
    #e6e6e8
    */
 
 html, body{
 height: 100%;
 }
 
 .bg {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
      background-color: #FFF;
    }
 .search {
      padding: 10%;
      max-width: 50%;
    }
 
 #results{
      padding: 10%;
 }
 
 .bg, .search, #results {
   flex: 1 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
 }
 
 /* Medium screens */
 @media all and (max-width: 800px) {
 .bg {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
 }
 
    span, h1{
      font-size: 2em;
      font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #000;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    .random{
 font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; 
 font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #000;
    }
    .title {
 font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bolder;
    }
 
 .wikiArticle {
   font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif:
      color: #FFF;
   margin: auto;
 }
    .wikiArticle:hover {
      background-color: #c43235;
      color: #FFF;
    }
 
 .wikiArticle a{
  color: #e6e6e8;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 
 .hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
 input{
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%;
 }
 
 #searchButton {
  color: #ccc;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
 }
 
 #searchButton:hover{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c43235;
  border-color: #c43235;
 }
 
 input:focus,
 select:focus,
 textarea:focus,
 button:focus {
  outline-color: #c43235;
 }
 
 .search img{
  vertical-align: baseline;
      width: 30%;
 }
  
 .search a{
  text-decoration: none;
 }
  
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="bg">
   <div class="search">
    <a href="https://www.mariokandut.com" target="_blank">
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1122px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png">
    </a>
    <span>Instant Search</span><br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type your query" name="searchTermInput" id="searchTermInput" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)">
    <button onclick="wikiSearch();" type="button" id="searchButton" class="btn">Go</button>
    <br />
    <span class="random">
     <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random" target="_blank">Random Magic</a>
    </span>
    
   </div>  
   <div id="results" class="hidden">
   <h1>Instant Results</h1>
    <div id="wikiOut0" class="wikiArticle">
     <a id="wikiLink0" href="" target="_blank">
      <p class="title" id="titleOut0"></p>
      <p id="snippetOut0"></p>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div id="wikiOut1" class="wikiArticle">
     <a id="wikiLink1" href="" target="_blank">
      <p class="title" id="titleOut1"></p>
      <p id="snippetOut1"></p>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div id="wikiOut2" class="wikiArticle">
     <a id="wikiLink2" href="" target="_blank">
      <p class="title" id="titleOut2"></p>
      <p id="snippetOut2"></p>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div id="wikiOut3" class="wikiArticle">
     <a id="wikiLink3" href="" target="_blank">
      <p class="title" id="titleOut3"></p>
      <p id="snippetOut3"></p>
     </a>
    </div>
    <div id="wikiOut4" class="wikiArticle">
     <a id="wikiLink4" href="" target="_blank">
      <p class="title" id="titleOut4"></p>
      <p id="snippetOut4"></p>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
 
 //function to make ENTER button a click
 function handleKeyPress(e){
 var key=e.keyCode || e.which; 
 if (key==13){ //check if button is enter button
  wikiSearch();
  };
 }
 
    function wikiSearch() {
   //Search via Generator API Method
      var searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchTermInput").value;
   //console.log(searchTerm);
   //Querylimit API (gsrlimit=5) limit outcome to 5 queries
   var queryLimit = 5;
   var wikiURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=" + queryLimit + "&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=" + searchTerm + "&format=json&callback&callback=?";
   console.log(wikiURL);
   $.getJSON(wikiURL, function(data){
  //Get PageID with Object.keys
  var pageID = Object.keys(data.query.pages);
  console.log(pageID);
  data.query.pages[pageID[0]].extract;
  for(var i=0; i < queryLimit; i++){
    document.getElementById("titleOut"+i).innerHTML = data.query.pages[pageID[i]].title;
    document.getElementById("snippetOut"+i).innerHTML = data.query.pages[pageID[i]].extract.substring(0,150) + "...";
    var objectLink = document.getElementById("wikiLink"+i);
    objectLink.setAttribute("href", "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" + pageID[i]);
    console.log(objectLink);
  };
  //Other option: Open Search https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch
  //var wikiURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchTerm + "&limit=5&namespace=0&format=json&callback=?"
  //Different Option, but no URL output possible. "list=search";
  //https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&continue=&srsearch=" + searchTerm + "&srwhat=text&srprop=size|wordcount|timestamp|snippet|titlesnippet&utf8=1&callback=?";
  $("#results").removeClass("hidden");
      });
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you remove the `<div>`s then what and where do you want the content to append to? Do have another plan for layout? Or you actually meant that you don't want to write so much HTML and want the placeholding `<div>` to be dynamic as well?

Comment: @zer00ne, exactly. The placeholder HTML divs need to be dynamic. What if the outcome should be 100 articles instead of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATED]** You need to remove all your placeholders, and need to make it dynamic in your script, you may please put the below block just before your `document.getElementById(...` assignments,

```
var wikiDiv= document.createElement('DIV');
    document.body.appendChild(wikiDiv);
    wikiDiv.innerHTML = '<div id="wikiOut'+i+'" class="wikiArticle"><a id="wikiLink'+i+'" href="" target="_blank"><p class="title" id="titleOut'+i+'"></p><p id="snippetOut'+i+'"></p></a></div>';
```

**Here is the working DEMO :** https://jsfiddle.net/fev60Lwn/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. That was also my thought, but I get an error. __Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null__  It seems that the loop won't work, because the ID of the HTML is wrong.

Comment: @Mario Please check my updated answer given above, and see the **working demo** in the given fiddle.

Comment: thanks, it works. The <div> is going to be generated outside the div results. so I changed this line and it works. document.getElementById("results").appendChild(wikiDiv);

Answer (score 0):

You can have one div as a template

```
        <div id="results" class="hidden">
        <h1>Instant Results</h1>
            <div id="wikiOut" class="wikiArticle" style="display:none">
                <a id="wikiLink" href="" target="_blank">
                    <p class="title" id="titleOut"></p>
                    <p id="snippetOut"></p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then clone it for each article

```
    $('.wikiArticle:not(#wikiOut)').remove();
    for(var i=0; i < queryLimit; i++){
            var tmpl = $('#wikiOut').clone();
            tmpl.find("#titleOut").attr('id',"titleOut"+i).html(data.query.pages[pageID[i]].title);
            tmpl.find("#snippetOut").attr('id',"snippetOut"+i).html(data.query.pages[pageID[i]].extract.substring(0,150) + "...");
            $("#wikiLink").attr({'id':"snippetOut"+i,"href": "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" + pageID[i]});
            tmpl.appendTo('#results').show();
            console.log(objectLink);
    };
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried your code and it's not working correctly. The code just puts one div under results out. If I type in another query, the new result will be shown under the old one.

Comment: Updated the answer to create a div per result and to clear the results every search

Comment: thanks. the code works after removing the console.log(objectLink), since the var is not defined anymore.